# Converting php array to newer square bracket version

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying use the new(ish) format square brackets for an array assigned to variables.

This is it in the old format:

```
$header = array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer ACCESSTOKEN','x-api-key: APIKEY','x-proxy-global-company-id: COMPANYID');
```

This is what the tutorial talks about for the style of new brakets:

```
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```

The items I want is like the following in my header:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ACCESSTOKEN
x-api-key: APIKEY
x-proxy-global-company-id: COMPANYID
```

Therefore I thought my header variable should be assigned an array like this:

```
$header = [
"Accept: application/json",
"Content-Type: application/json",
"Authorization: Bearer ACCESSTOKEN",
"x-api-key: APIKEY",
"x-proxy-global-company-id: COMPANYID",
];
```

This doesn't validate so I know I'm wrong. It says unexpected T string on line 5. Can anyone give me a tip on where I have gone wrong please?

Comment: _unexpected T shirt_ there is no *T shirt*?

Comment: How did your code look like before you've changed it to the new format?

Comment: @NicoHaase Ive put that at the top of the question

Comment: The newer array looks fine to me. Is line 5 one of the lines in that array?

Comment: You have an extra `,` at the end of the last line in the array that shouldn't be there `"x-proxy-global-company-id: COMPANYID",`

Comment: @Nick trailing commas are okay in PHP arrays, right?

Comment: new(ish) is a very generous way of putting it. My suspicion is in your conversion you not only converted `array()` to `[]` but also switched single quotes to double quotes. The escaping rules of  double quotes are different so maybe there's some "special" characters in the api key (not shown here) that are breaking the string

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes they are but they offend me :-)

Comment: @Nick haha fair enough :-)

Comment: Yes, the trailing comma is fine.  Your new code and old code are equivalent (and bracket notation is nowhere near new.)

Comment: How does the code look like that performs the API call? Have you tried using **both** notations side by side and perform `array_diff` or dumping both and check for the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header should be like below:

```
$header = [
    "Accept" => "application/json",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    "Authorization" => "Bearer ACCESSTOKEN",
    "x-api-key" => "APIKEY",
    "x-proxy-global-company-id" => "COMPANYID",
];
```

Comment: Aren't the values of this array supposed to be the entire HTTP header strings?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes that's where I am confused really